# Qt translation, get original untranslated string

Tags: qt

I've implemented language support in an application I've been writing which outputs data in JSON objects which is viewable using a separate web interface which reads the JSON objects. No matter what language I am using, I want to be able to output the English (default string passed to the tr() macro). Is there an easy way to get this? It seems like what I'm after is the opposite to the tr() macro?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613339/qt-convert-translated-text-to-english/31620130#31620130

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Such a shame that the reverse lookup isn't available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt convert translated text to english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613339/qt-convert-translated-text-to-english)